# Why does ReadBatchAsync throw FileNotFound exception

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

Investigating the following Windows 10 appointment code  and the call to `ReadBatchAsync` throws a `FileNotFound exception` saying the "`device is not ready`".

```
AppointmentStore store = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite);

AppointmentStoreChangeReader reader = store.ChangeTracker.GetChangeReader();

IReadOnlyList<AppointmentStoreChange> changes = await reader.ReadBatchAsync();
```

Any idea why?

Comment: did you checked the value of reader?